# c++ multithreaded windows GUI (accessing the forms)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, user-interface, wrapper

I've written a simple console application using windows sockets to work as a proxy between a server and a client. I decided to make a graphical interface for watching all the in/outgoing packets real time (like a very simple wireshark).

The connection between the server and the client runs on a different thread than the message loop. When the server/client sends a packet, I would like that to be displayed (for example added to a simple text control) immediately.

But since I can not access the forms from other thread than the thread where the message loop is I dont know how to handle this.

I've found several solutions in:
- Managed c++
- C++/CLI
- C#,
but not any without using .NET platform. (I really new to this GUI topic so I am not even sure you can use windows forms without .NET)

Maybe QT + C++ could handle this problem, but any other solution than that? If not is it possible to write a wrapper in C# / Java for the native C++ code?

There must be many applications written in C/C++ which using a GUI, what is the general way to do that?

Comment: Post custom messages to the dialog from your secondary threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct that you cannot access a window in a different thread.  The proper way to handle this to post a message using the ::PostMessage Win32 API command (or, if you are using a wrapper library around Win32, whatever function in that wrapper that eventually calls PostMessage).  Here's a useful link from Microsoft regarding message queues: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative one, free and open-source, called Nana C++ Library (http://stdex.sourceforge.net), a pure C++ GUI library. 
By using Nana library, the multithreading issue can be fixed easily. There is [an article](http://nanaproject.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/a-method-to-prevent-ui-from-blocking-while-busy/) on the multithreading in GUI, it would be a choice for your hobby project.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty Win32 solution would involve a critical section, a text buffer, and a timer in the UI thread.

Define a few globals...

```
CRITICAL_SECTION bufferLock; // critical section (to be initialized somewhere)
char dataBuffer[65536]; // contains the data that will be sent to the form
int newdata = 0; // how much data we got (this variable must be atomic, int is ok)
char uiDataBuffer[65536]; // data available to the form
int overflow = 0; // just in case...
```

UI thread timer

```
void onTimer ()
{
     if (overflow)
     {
          // handle this
     }
     else
     if (newdata) // new data to display
     {
          // take the lock, copy the data and release the lock quickly
          EnterCriticalSection(&bufferLock);
          int dataread = newdata;
          memcpy(uiDataBuffer, dataBuffer, dataread);
          newdata = 0;
          LeaveCriticalSection(&bufferLock);

          // TODO: append the text in uiDataBuffer[] to your text control
     }
}
```

To be called from the worker thread:

```
void sendData (char* data, int size)
{
    EnterCriticalSection (&bufferLock);
    if(size+newdata > 65536)
        overflow = 1;
    else
    {
        memcpy(dataBuffer+newdata, data, size);
        newdata += size;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection (&bufferLock);
}
```

Code untested. Buffer size and timer frequency are to be adjusted.

It is possible to avoid polling the buffer with the timer by using PostMessage() (with a custom message) to signal the UI that new data is available.

If performance is an issue, data exchange between a producer and a consumer thread can also be performed very efficiently with a lock-free FIFO queue.

PostMessage() alone *is not a solution* to exchange data between threads.

Comment: Both answer was really helpful, thanks for them. Is there any elegant way to use custom messages? (I mean if I use a custom message - let it be PACKET_ARRIVED - it must have a type of int. How to be sure that it's value is not in conflict with other constants? Should I simply use a number that is "big enough" to avoid conflicts?

Comment: Use RegisterWindowMessage() to obtain an unique "custom" message.