# User I/O on threads C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, nana

I have some code here that consists of a class for a window (using Nana C++) and a few threads for networking. However, I can't seem to be able to output to the user in any way. I've tried appending to a text box, using a message box, printing to console, but it won't show up. Is this a problem with Nana or Boost.Thread?

If it's a problem with Boost.Thread I can switch to std::thread but I don't think it's going to work.

```
void thread()//Let's say this function is started on a thread and the window is started on main
{
    append(L"append test");
    MsgBox(L"msgbox test"):
}
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735830/c-multithreaded-windows-gui-accessing-the-forms

Comment: On some platforms you can only draw to the GUI from the main thread.  Using stdio should always work though.

Comment: @west So i went down on that question and found the answer about Nana. You're suggesting i change from Boost.Thread to nana::thread or nana::thread_pool? Sounds interesting, i'll experiment with that.

Comment: No what I was thinking is that you need to communicate accross those threads and you need some way using messaging or some other IPC mechanism to communicate you can create the message box but if the window isn't on the same thread it can't display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a Nana demo that illustrate how to append texts in other thread.

```
#include <nana/gui.hpp>
#include <nana/gui/widgets/textbox.hpp>
#include <nana/gui/widgets/button.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace nana;

    form fm(API::make_center(300, 250));

    textbox txt(fm, rectangle(10, 10, 280, 190));
    button btn(fm, rectangle(10, 220, 200, 20));
    btn.caption("append texts in other thread");

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condvar;
    volatile bool running = true;

    std::thread thrd([&]
    {
        while(running)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            condvar.wait(lock);

            txt.append(L"append a new line\n", false);

            msgbox mb(L"hello");
            mb<<L"This is a demo";
            mb.show();
        }
    });

    btn.events().click([&]
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        condvar.notify_one();
    });

    fm.events().unload([&]
    {
        running = false;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        condvar.notify_one();   
    });

    fm.show();
    exec();
    thrd.join();
}
```

This demo is created with Nana C++ Library 1.0.2 and works fine on Windows/Linux

Comment: IMO, isn't using a bool value to check if a thread is running kind of bad? Since the definition of `volatile` isn't really standardized too well, this isn't really portable.